# Set up machines to call home for software updates

Tags: windows, svn, deployment, service, wix

I have a hardware product which includes a windows PC, which has two software components which we would like to occasionally update. One is installed via a WiX MSI installer with a version number, the other is a SVN checkout (I cannot alter either of these approaches).

We have a number of these machines, both on the factory floor, and out with customers. I may want to update the install on a subset of machines for testing before rolling out to all, e.g. required versions might be:

Machine |  SVN revision |  MSI version

001     |     6000     |    1.0.4

002     |     6000     |   1.0.4

003     |     6250     |    1.0.5

004     |     6250     |    1.0.5

005     |     6500     |    1.0.6

## My Idea

I'm trying to come up with a reliable way of updating software, and at the moment have the idea of having a publically accessible web page that would hold the above data.  Each machine would have a service running which would periodically check the website, and it's own line, comparing the SVN and MSI values against what's currently on the machine, then, if applicable:

a) update the SVN-linked folder to the specified revision

b) download and run the applicable MSI installer (which might include updates to the updater service)

Of course, just because that's the first idea I had, doesn't make it the best one, or even good, so I thought I'd ask you all about how you might approach this in a reliable, gracefully failing manner.

Any thoughts?

Comment: One random thing you're not mentioning if you're pushing updates centrally like this; sign (and check the signature of) the updates so that the PC's won't be convinced to install malware in case your update site is hacked.

Comment: It's really too bad that you can't change how the software is distributed, because SVN **is not a software distribution tool**. I mean, it can work, but it'll work in the same way that using a wrench to drive roofing nails "works".

Comment: I'd happily consider a solution for the MSI part, then use its success to try to bully through a switch on the SVN side of things.

Comment: It seems like using System Center (or whatever MS is calling SCCM this week) would be a better way to go. You can push installations out (bonus points if your MSI allows for a scripted/unattended install) through it and section your systems off into "collections" so you can push to that limited group of test machines first before pushing it out everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that automatic updater apps typically run is that you supply a web service (not a web page). Your app running on the client system periodically calls into the web service passing the ProductCode, UpgradeCode, ProductVersion of the MSI setup. The web site maintains a data set that tells the caller if there is a patch, minor update or complete upgrade available (there are at least three ways to update a product!). Then the app downloads the MSI and (depending on the UI situation) asks about whether to install it or not. If each system has only limited users they probably can't install it. If the site has a central distribution mechanism then alroc's suggestion is the best one - use system center, group policy, Active Directory type mechanisms to push the update to each system.

In your test case, candidate beta machines can be marked with a "beta" designation, such as a registry item, and when the app calls into the web service it can say it's a beta tester and get early versions of the setup.

Having a service call a web service and download an install a setup can have its issues, especially if you run with the system account, so having it in the running app might be safer.

All that might be overkill if you just want a simple web page for people to go look at. Just be careful that you download the updated MSI into an actual safe permanent location and not into the browser's temp folder where it will get removed.

Anyway, hopefully there are some useful ideas there.